# Sub menu's overriding dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a vertical dropdown menu right but the sub menu's keeps overriding the actual menu. I've tried looking around but can't find a solution anywhere..
Anybody a little smarter than me, care to enlighten me?

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Magnolia/3czzbhes/

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

/*Index*/

#index {
  background-image: url(../img/metallica/Metallica_London_2008-09-15_Kirk_and_JamesBL.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center 10;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
#venstre {
  float: left;
}
#midt {
  float: left;
}
#header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: auto;
}
#header a {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Cinzel', serif, 'Cinzel Decorative', cursive;
  font-size: 60px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 32px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-right: 650px;
  position: relative;
}
#header form {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 26px;
  margin-right: 49px;
}
#righto {
  float: right;
}
#lefto {
  float: left;
}
#Wrapper {
  clear: both;
}
.anker {
  width: 67px;
  height: 52px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 147px;
  margin-top: 207px;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
}
.anker a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.anker ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.undercirkel {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.undercirkelt {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 800px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.undercirkeltr {
  margin-top: 390px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.box {
  float: left;
  width: 700px;
  height: 390px;
  margin-left: 428px;
  margin-top: 270px;
  background-image: url(../img/bg.png);
  z-index: -1;
}
.box form {
  display: inline-block;
}
.box .email {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.box {
  padding: 15px;
}
.boxt {
  float: left;
  width: 700px;
  height: 390px;
  margin-left: 428px;
  background-image: url(../img/bg.png);
  z-index: -1;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 15px;
}
.boxtr {
  float: left;
  width: 700px;
  height: 390px;
  margin-left: 428px;
  background-image: url(../img/bg.png);
  z-index: -1;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 15px;
}
.boxf {
  float: left;
  width: 700px;
  height: 390px;
  margin-left: 428px;
  background-image: url(../img/bg.png);
  z-index: -1;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 15px;
}
.boxfe {
  float: left;
  width: 700px;
  height: 390px;
  margin-left: 428px;
  background-image: url(../img/bg.png);
  z-index: -1;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 15px;
}
.boxfe h2 {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-left: 240px;
}
.boxfe table {
  text-align: center;
}
.dropdown {
  width: auto;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 190px;
}
.dropdown a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Cinzel', serif, 'Cinzel Decorative', cursive;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 2px 0 2px 0;
}
.dropdown a:hover {
  color: #282828;
}
.dropdown ul a {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.drop {
  background-color: #393939;
  border: #D4D4D4;
}
.drop li:hover {
  background-color: #808080;
  border: #D4D4D4;
}
.underundermenu {
  display: none;
}
.underundermenu li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.underundermenu li {
  clear: both;
  background-color: #393939;
}
.dropdown li:hover .underundermenu {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
.dropdown li:hover .underundermenu li {
  float: left;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.undermenu {
  display: none;
}
.undermenu li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.undermenu li {
  clear: both;
  background-color: #393939;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
.dropdown li:hover .undermenu {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: auto;
}
.dropdown li:hover .undermenu li {
  float: left;
  font-size: 13px;
}
#right {
  width: 300px;
  background-image: url(../img/bg.png);
  float: right;
  margin-right: 52px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: 1250px;
}
#right img {
  padding: 15px;
}
.space {
  padding-top: 5em;
}
.footer {
  clear: both;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 150px;
}
/* Kontakt */

#kontakt {
  background-image: url(../img/metallica/Metallica_London_2008-09-15_Kirk_and_JamesBL.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center 10;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Rockentusiasterne | Hjem</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cinzel' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="../img/favicon.gif" />
  <script src="../js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/js.js"></script>
  <script>
    var windw = this;

    $.fn.followTo = function(pos) {
      var $this = this,
        $window = $(window);

      $window.scroll(function(e) {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > pos) {
          $this.css({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: pos
          });
        } else {
          $this.css({
            position: 'fixed',
            top: 40
          });
        }
      });
    };



    $('#scrollto-wrapper').followTo(250);
  </script>
</head>

<body id="index">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="lefto"><a href="index.html">Rockentusiasterne</a>
    </div>
    <div id="righto">
      <form>
        <label>
          <img src="../img/search.png">
        </label>
        <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Søg">
        </input>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="Wrapper">
    <div id="left">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <ul>
          <div class="drop">
            <li><a href="index.html">Forside</a>
            </li>
          </div>
          <div class="drop">
            <li><a href="index.html">Genrer</a>
              <ul class="undermenu">
                <li><a href="#">Rock'n'Roll</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Alternativ musik</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Grunge</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </div>
          <div class="drop">
            <li><a href="omos.html">Om os</a>
            </li>
          </div>
          <div class="drop">
            <li><a href="Forum.html">Forum</a>
              <ul class="undermenu">
                <li><a href="#">Opret bruger</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">FAQ</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </div>
          <div class="drop">
            <li><a href="Kontakt.html">Kontakt os</a>
            </li>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="innerwrapper">
      <div id="midt">
        <div class="anker">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#1">
                <img src="../img/cirkel.png">
              </a>
            </li>
            <div class="undercirkel">
              <li>
                <img src="../img/undercirkel.png">
              </li>
            </div>
            <div class="undercirkel">
              <li>
                <img src="../img/undercirkel.png">
              </li>
            </div>
            <li>
              <a href="#2">
                <img src="../img/cirkel.png">
              </a>
            </li>
            <div class="undercirkel">
              <li>
                <img src="../img/undercirkel.png">
              </li>
            </div>
            <div class="undercirkel">
              <li>
                <img src="../img/undercirkel.png">
              </li>
            </div>
            <li>
              <a href="#3">
                <img src="../img/cirkel.png">
              </a>
            </li>
            <div class="undercirkel">
              <li>
                <img src="../img/undercirkel.png">
              </li>
            </div>
            <div class="undercirkel">
              <li>
                <img src="../img/undercirkel.png">
              </li>
            </div>
            <li>
              <a href="#4">
                <img src="../img/cirkel.png">
              </a>
            </li>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          <a name="1"></a>
          <h1>Elvis Presley</h1>
          <h2>Fra Wikipedia, den frie encyklopædi</h2>
          <p>Elvis Aaron Presley (8. januar 1935 i Tupelo, Mississippi, USA – 16. august 1977 i Memphis, Tennessee), amerikansk sanger, guitarist og filmskuespiller.</p>
          <p>Elvis Presley er også kendt som The King of Rock 'n' roll eller slet og ret The King.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="undercirkelt">
          <li>
            <img src="../img/undercirkelt.png">
          </li>
        </div>
        <div class="undercirkelt">
          <li>
            <img src="../img/undercirkelt.png">
          </li>
        </div>
        <div class="undercirkelt">
          <li>
            <img src="../img/undercirkelt.png">
          </li>
        </div>
        <div class="undercirkelt">
          <li>
            <img src="../img/undercirkelt.png">
          </li>
        </div>
        <div class="undercirkelt">
          <li>
            <img src="../img/undercirkelt.png">
          </li>
        </div>
        <div class="undercirkelt">
          <li>
            <img src="../img/undercirkelt.png">
          </li>
        </div>
        <div class="undercirkelt">
          <li>
            <img src="../img/undercirkelt.png">
          </li>
        </div>
        <div class="undercirkelt">
          <li>
            <img src="../img/undercirkelt.png">
          </li>
        </div>
        <div class="undercirkelt">
          <li>
            <img src="../img/undercirkelt.png">
          </li>
        </div>
        <div class="undercirkelt">
          <li>
            <img src="../img/undercirkelt.png">
          </li>
        </div>

        <div class="boxt">
          <a name="2"></a>
          <h2>Barndom</h2>
          <h3>Tupelo</h3>
          <p>Elvis blev født i et fattigt arbejderhjem på Old Saltillo Road i EastTupelo, et to-rums træhus, bygget af hans far, Vernon.</p>
          <p>Tvillingebroderen Jesse Garon Presley var døde ved fødslen, og Elvis voksede op som ene barn. Som 13-årig flyttede han i november 1948 med sine forældre til Memphis. Hans fødehjem i den østlige ende af Tupelo er i dag indrettet som museum og
            er den mest besøgte bygning i byen. Old Saltillo Road, hvor huset ligger, er efter Elvis’ død omdøbt og hedder i dag Elvis Presley Drive.</p>
          <p>Byens turisme er i høj grad centreret omkring Elvis Presley.</p>

          <h3>Memphis</h3>
          <p>I Memphis boede familien Presley i et af de fattigste kvarterer, hvor der var en nær tilknytning til den lokale kirke. I kirken kom Elvis tit på besøg sammen med sin mor. Og det var her han fik de første musikalske erfaringer, da han både hørte
            og sang gospel.
            <p>Familien var meget fattig og skiftede ofte bopæl. De holdt sig for det meste til det samme kvarter i byen, så sønnen kunne beholde sin skole.</p>
            <p>Elvis gik i skole på Humes High School på North Manasas Street i Memphis.</p>
            <p>Den 9. april 1953 optrådte han ved den årlige skolefest med sangen "Keep Them Cold Icy Fingers Off Of Me" og efter et bragende bifald sang han som ekstranummer "Till I Waltz Again With You".</p>
            <p>3. juni 1953 var Elvis færdig med sin skolegang. Fra han forlod skolen og til sit gennembrud som 18- årig ernærede han sig som lastbilchauffør og arbejdsmand hos det lokale el-firma, The Crown Electric Company, til den formidable timeløn af
              1,25 $.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="undercirkeltr">
          <div class="undercirkelt">
            <li>
              <img src="../img/undercirkelt.png">
            </li>
          </div>
          <div class="undercirkelt">
            <li>
              <img src="../img/undercirkelt.png">
            </li>
          </div>
          <div class="undercirkelt">
            <li>
              <img src="../img/undercirkelt.png">
            </li>
          </div>
          <div class="undercirkelt">
            <li>
              <img src="../img/undercirkelt.png">
            </li>
          </div>
          <div class="undercirkelt">
            <li>
              <img src="../img/undercirkelt.png">
            </li>
          </div>
          <div class="undercirkelt">
            <li>
              <img src="../img/undercirkelt.png">
            </li>
          </div>
          <div class="undercirkelt">
            <li>
              <img src="../img/undercirkelt.png">
            </li>
          </div>
          <div class="undercirkelt">
            <li>
              <img src="../img/undercirkelt.png">
            </li>
          </div>
          <div class="undercirkelt">
            <li>
              <img src="../img/undercirkelt.png">
            </li>
          </div>
          <div class="undercirkelt">
            <li>
              <img src="../img/undercirkelt.png">
            </li>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="boxtr"><a name="3"><h2>Begyndelsen på karrieren</h2>
<h3>Tiden hos SUN Records</h3>
<p>Den 18. juli 1953 indspillede Elvis, for egen regning, sangene "My Happiness" og "That´s When Your Heartaches Begin" i Sam 
Phillips' studie Sun Records i Memphis. Det var angiveligt en fødselsdagsgave til sin mor. (Dog er det bemærkelsesværdigt, at 
moderen Gladys havde fødselsdag d. 25 april)</p>
<p>5. – 6. juli 1954 tog Elvis tilbage til Sun for at indspille endnu en plade, men uden helt at ramme den lyd, som han ønskede.
Med i studiet var guitaristen Scotty Moore og bassisten Bill Black, der begge var studiemusikere tilknyttet Sun Records.
Under en pause i optagelserne begyndte Presley at eksperimentere for sjov med sangen "That's All Right", og de andre to 
jammede med. "That's All Right" kendte Elvis fra en pladeindspilning fra 1949 med Arthur (Big Boy) Crudup, der selv havde 
skrevet sangen. Men Elvis og de to studiemusikere forsøgte sig nu med sangen i en langt mere rocket udgave, end den 
oprindelige. Sam Phillips optog dem på bånd, her var den lyd, som de havde søgt.</p> <p>Gruppen indspillede dernæst "Blue Moon 
of Kentucky" et bluegrass nummer oprindeligt skrevet og fremført i 3/4-taktart af Bill Monroe i 1946. De to numre blev 
udsendt som single den 19. juli. Phillips havde længe været på jagt efter en hvid sanger, der lød sort, og med Elvis havde han 
fundet den rigtige sound.</p><p>Den 7. juli, dagen efter pladen var indspillet, blev "That's All Right" spillet for første gang i radioen. Det var på den lokale 
radiostation WHBQ, og det var dermed den lokale disc jockey, Dewey Phillips (ikke relateret til Sam Phillips), der blev den 
første i verden, der spillede en Elvis-plade i radioen. Lytterne var så begejstrede for pladen, at han denne dag spillede den 
fjorten gange på sit program, og efter adskillige opringninger fra lytterne fik han samme aften hentet Elvis ind til sit første 
radiointerview.</p>
<p>Fra februar 1955 og til november samme år turnerede Elvis sammen med sit band The Blue Moon Boys. Bandet bestod af 
Elvis Presley, vokal og rytmeguitar, Scotty Moore, leadguitar, Bill Black, bas og D.J. Fontana, trommer. Bandet blev opløst da 
Sun solgte Elvis' kontrakt, men blev også i årene herefter ved med at arbejde sammen.</p>
<p>Elvis indspillede i alt 20 sange mens han var hos Sun. De to af dem er gået tabt, mens de resterende 18 sange er i behold. Ti 
af disse blev udgivet af Sun i 1954-55 som Elvis' fem første singleplader.
I stald hos RCA</p>
<p>Den 18. august 1955 blev 'Oberst' Tom Parker manager for Elvis Presley. Parker var ambitiøs og havde øje for Presleys 
kæmpepotentiale. Han gik straks i gang med at finde et pladeselskab af en størrelse, som Parker mente havde kapaciteten til 
et landsdækkende gennembrud for hans kunstner.</p>
<p>Sun Records solgte i november 1955 Presleys kontrakt til RCA Victor for 40.000,- dollars (heraf 5.000,- direkte til Elvis), på 
daværende tidspunkt den største kontraktsum nogensinde. Elvis' første pladeudgivelse hos RCA var "Heartbreak Hotel".</p>
<p>I 1956 bragede Elvis Presley igennem på den nationale scene – og også snart den internationale – med en lyd og stil, som 
kombinerede mange af de musikelementer, han havde mødt. Elvis nedbrød på mange måder de sociale og racemæssige 
barrierer i tiden og indvarslede en ny æra i amerikansk populærmusik. Hans sceneoptræden var dynamisk og præget af 
rullende hoftebevægelser af en hidtil uset seksuelt udfordrende karakter.</p>
<p>Ca. et år efter overgangen til RCA, nærmere bestemt den 4. december 1956, var Elvis på besøg hos Sun. Her var der andre 
unge kunstnere til stede, og der opstod en spontan jam-session. Tilstede var, udover Elvis Presley, Carl Perkins, Johnny 
Cash og Jerry Lee Lewis. Denne happening blev optaget på bånd af Sam Phillips og udsendt mange år senere under titlen The 
Million Dollar Quartet. En titel, der blev anvendt som overskrift af et lokalt dagblad allerede dagen efter, da den siden så 
berømte happening blev omtalt.</p>
<p>I 1957 købte Elvis Graceland som hjem for både sig selv og sine forældre. Købsprisen var 102.000 dollars, og med købet var 
familien Presleys hyppige adresseskift forbi.</p>
<h3>Salg af plader</h3>
<p>For bl.a. at sikre sig rettighederne til sine sange m.m. entrerede Elvis Presley med et musikforlag, Hill & Range Music 
Company. </p>
<p>I takt med at Elvis' popularitet steg ønskede forlaget en tættere kontakt til ham, og i 1956 oprettedes de to firmaer 'Elvis 
Presley Music Inc.' og 'Gladys Music Inc.' som Elvis og Parker var medejere af. Dette arrangement betød i virkeligheden, at 
hvis en sang skulle synges af Elvis, skulle aftalen foregå gennem Hill & Range, som pressede på overfor sangskriverne for at 
få Elvis føjet til som medforfatter. Denne form for afpresning virkede kun på de nye og usikre sangskrivere, mens de mere 
professionelle ikke ville acceptere dette og dermed blev skræmt bort.
I sidste ende var det Elvis, der led under disse tilstande, idet hans sangmateriale dermed blev ringere og ringere, hvilket 
salgskurverne op gennem 1960'erne også vidner om.</p>
<h3>Salg af merchandise</h3><p>Med det formål at sælge Elvis-relateret merchandise, så som T-shirts, postkort, tasker, håndklæder etc., alt sammen med 
Elvis' navn eller foto på, blev firmaet Elvis Presley Enterprises oprettet. Selskabet blev grundlagt på adressen Union Avenue 
nr. 160 i Memphis i 1955 af Elvis Presley og Bob Neal, der var Presleys manager før Tom Parker fik jobbet. Firmaet har 
eksisteret lige siden og er i dag en kæmpeforretning.</p>
<h3>Memphis-mafiaen</h3>
<p>Memphis-mafiaen er navnet på den stab af bodyguards, sikkerhedsfolk og medhjælpende venner, der konstant befandt sig i 
nærheden af Elvis Presley. Der var tale om en klike på – i perioder – op til 30 personer. Det startede allerede tidligt i hans 
karriere og fortsatte til hans død. Selve navnet fik de i Las Vegas i starten af1960'erne, da gruppen på en løssluppen tur i 
byen havde mødt en journalist på en natklub. Hun skrev i næste dags avis en artikel, hvori hun kaldte dem "The Memphis 
Mafia" som en pendant til Frank Sinatras "The Rat Pack". Navnet blev hængende, selv om Elvis selv yndede at kalde dem 
"El's Angels" – "Elvis' Engle"</p>
<p>Gruppen stod til disposition for Elvis døgnet rundt og fungerede som et menneskeligt værn mod verden udenfor. De fulgte 
ukritisk Elvis' mindste vink og fik til gengæld løn, dyre gaver, så som smykker, ure og biler. Medlemmer af Memphis-mafiaen 
måtte alle underkaste sig en ubetinget tavshedspligt. Den blev faktisk først brudt kort før Elvis' død, da to af dem udsendte 
den afslørende bog "Elvis, What Happened?", der stillede kritiske spørgsmål til Elvis Presleys levevis.</p>
<h3>Militærtjenesten</h3>
<p>Fra 1958 til 1960 aftjente Elvis sin værnepligt i Vesttyskland. Han boede i Bad Nauheim mens han var udstationeret i 
nabobyen Friedberg, hjemsted for den amerikanske militærbase Ray Barracks. 
De sidste 15 måneder af Elvis' ophold i byen boede han med sin nærmeste familie og venner i et lejet privathus i 
Goethestrasse 14. Det var her, han første gang mødte sin senere hustru Priscilla, datter af en officer i Ray Barracks.
Elvis Presley vendte hjem fra Tyskland den 2. marts 1960 og blev hjemsendt tre dage senere, den 5. marts, med rang af
sergent.</p>
<h3>I gang igen</h3>
<p>Elvis var spændt på, om hans mange fans havde holdt ved eller om de havde svigtet ham mens han var i Tyskland. Men Tom 
Parker havde sørget for, at RCA jævnligt udsendte plader med Elvis mens han var soldat. Og da soundtracket fra hans første 
film efter soldatertiden, G.I.Blues, var på LP-hitlisten i USA i 111 uger i træk, var det tydeligt for enhver, at successen atter 
var hjemme. Snart tordnede han frem igen med millionsælgende sange som "It's Now Or Never", "Are You Lonesome 
Tonight?" og "Kiss Me Quick".</p>
<p>På daværende tidspunkt syntes Elvis Presleys plads på toppen af pop-tronen som nærmest urørlig. Han anslås at have solgt 
over 1 milliard plader. I USA alene har han fået guld-, platin- eller multiplatin-belønninger for 140 forskellige albums og 
singler.</p>
<h3>De store koncerter</h3>
<p>Fra 1969 og frem til hans død stod der turné og liveoptræden på programmet, hovedsageligt på International Hotel i Las 
Vegas, men også i mange andre byer rundt om i U.S.A. (Elvis har aldrig optrådt i Europa, kun i U.S.A. og Canada).</p>
<p>Den største af de mange koncerter var Aloha From Hawaii fra 14. januar 1973, hvor over 1,2 milliarder TV-seere så Elvis via 
satellit. Det var en velgørenhedskoncert for kræftforskning og den første gang nogensinde, at en TV-udsendelse blev 
transmitteret til hele verden. Der var i virkeligheden tale om to koncerter, den første afholdt 12. januar. Denne blev båndet 
og holdt i reserve til øjeblikkelig udsendelse som erstatning for "den rigtige", hvis nu et eller andet skulle kikse i den direkte transmission. Dette blev dog ikke nødvendigt. Så den koncert, der blev transmitteret 14. januar var, som planlagt, koncert 
nr. 2, direkte live-TV fra Hawaii. For begge show gælder, at Elvis var iklædt en hvid jumpsuit med "den amerikanske ørn" i 
pailletter på ryggen.</p>
<p>Elvis' sidste sceneoptræden var på Market Square Arena i Indianapolis og fandt sted den 26. juni 1977.</p></a>
        </div>
        <div class="undercirkeltr">
          <div class="undercirkelt">
            <li>
              <img src="../img/undercirkelt.png">
            </li>
          </div>
          <div class="undercirkelt">
            <li>
              <img src="../img/undercirkelt.png">
            </li>
          </div>
          <div class="undercirkelt">
            <li>
              <img src="../img/undercirkelt.png">
            </li>
          </div>
          <div class="undercirkelt">
            <li>
              <img src="../img/undercirkelt.png">
            </li>
          </div>
          <div class="undercirkelt">
            <li>
              <img src="../img/undercirkelt.png">
            </li>
          </div>
          <div class="undercirkelt">
            <li>
              <img src="../img/undercirkelt.png">
            </li>
          </div>
          <div class="undercirkelt">
            <li>
              <img src="../img/undercirkelt.png">
            </li>
          </div>
          <div class="undercirkelt">
            <li>
              <img src="../img/undercirkelt.png">
            </li>
          </div>
          <div class="undercirkelt">
            <li>
              <img src="../img/undercirkelt.png">
            </li>
          </div>
          <div class="undercirkelt">
            <li>
              <img src="../img/undercirkelt.png">
            </li>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="boxf">
          <h2>Død som 42-årig</h2>
          <p>Elvis og Priscilla blev gift 1. maj 1967 i Las Vegas. 1. februar 1968 blev datteren Lisa Marie født. Ægteskabet varede til den 23. februar 1972 hvor Elvis og Priscilla blev separeret og dernæst skilt den 9. oktober 1973.</p>
          <p>På grund af forkert kost blev Elvis i sine sidste leveår stadig mere og mere overvægtig. Han var ofte på slankekur, men tog hurtigt på i vægt igen. Elvis blev gradvist afhængig af både sovemedicin og opkvikkende medicin.
            <p>
              <p>Hans personlige læge, George Nichopoulos, mistede sin autorisation i en tre måneders periode på grund af dårlig rådgivning og for at have givet Elvis for meget receptpligtig medicin.</p>
              <p>Den 16. august 1977, dagen før den planlagte start på endnu en turne, blev Elvis Presley kl. 2.33 om morgenen fundet liggende livløs på sit badeværelsesgulv hjemme i Graceland. Trods ihærdige genoplivningsforsøg, såvel hjemme som på hospitalet,
                blev han erklæret død på Baptist Memorial Hospital i Memphis kl. 15.30. Den egentlige dødsårsag blev aldrig officielt fastslået, men blev angivet som "uregelmæssig hjertefunktion".</p>
              <p>Elvis blev efter sin død begravet på kirkegården Forrest Hill Cemetery på Elvis Presley Boulevard i Memphis. Der var imidlertid så stor opmærksomhed omkring hans gravsted, at han den 2. oktober 1977 sammen med sin mors jordiske rester blev
                genbegravet på Graceland. Nu er både Elvis, hans forældre, Vernon og Gladys Presley, samt hans farmor, Minnie Mae Presley, begravet i parken ved Graceland i den del som kaldes The Meditation Gardens.</p>
              <p>The Meditation Gardens blev åbnet for offentligheden den 27. november 1977. Graceland er i dag indrettet som Elvis-museum og besøges årligt af flere end 600.000 mennesker fra hele verden, i USA kun overgået af Det Hvide Hus.</p>
              <a name="4"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="right">
        <img src="../img/elvis/Elvis_Presley_promoting_Jailhouse_Rock.jpg" width="81" height="60">
        <iframe width="300" height="195" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/SBmAPYkPeYU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">Designet og udført af <a href="https://www.facebook.com/LikeAMusicBox">Christina L. Pedersen</a>
      </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set the `left` positioning to 0 and reset the default `padding` and `margin` on the `ul`:

```
.dropdown li:hover .undermenu {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  overflow:auto;
  left: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3czzbhes/2/)

UPDATE:

Yeah so set `position: relative;` on the parent (which is `.drop`) and add `top: 0` to `.undermenu`:

[NEW FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3czzbhes/3/)

Comment: Thanks so much! Do you also know how to make the sub menus stay a little so you can reach them before they fade?