# menu's dropdown occupies only the navbar space + hover not working

Tags: html, css, hover, navbar

I want to create a dropdown nav menu with a modal like box appearing on hover.

Here in my example, Products heading needs to open 4 columns of subheadings that align themselves into a bootstrap like grid.

I am close to the result but I am facing a couple of hurdles: my hover does not seem to work. Also, my subheading appears only within the perimeter of my navbar - whereas I want it to appear a little below the navbar, with some padding.

I looked at these 2 examples but they did not help me:

[stackoverflow reference 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26325730/sub-menus-overriding-dropdown-menu)

[stackoverflow reference 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32556146/fixed-dropdown-menu)

Please find the code and guide me in the right direction:

```css
.topnav {
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
 }

 .topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: grey;
 }
 .nav {
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
 }
 .nav li:first-child {
  margin-right: auto;
 }

 .nav li {
  position: relative;
 }

 .dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
 }

 .dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 560px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 20;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 80px;
  height: 220px;
 }

 .dropdown-content ul {
  display: block;
 }

 .arrow-up {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
 }

 .noshow {
  display: none;
 }

 .dropdown-content:hover .noshow {
  display: block
 }

 .subheading {
  font-weight: 700;
 }
```

```html
<nav class="topnav">
    <ul class="nav">
     <li><a class="active" href="#title"> Title</a></li>
     <li>

      <a href="#" class="icon icon-after icon-chevrondown dropdown">Products</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content arrow-up noshow">
          <ul class="column large-3 each-column">
           <li class="subheading">subheading</li>
            <li>
             <a href="#">subheading1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
             <a href="#">subheading2</a>
            </li>
                        <li>
             <a href="#">subheading3</a>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">link2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">link3</a></li>
     <li><a href="#account"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/30/30/" width="30" height="30" alt="User Account Icon"></a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
    .left_menu {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
    }

    .right_menu {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
    }

    .right_menu ul {
        float: right;
    }

    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: white;
    }

    li {
        float: left;
    }

    li a,
    .dropbtn {
        display: inline-block;
        color: grey;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    li a:hover,
    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
        /* background-color: red;*/
        /*color: white;*/
    }

    li.dropdown {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="left_menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Title</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="right_menu" style="float: left; width: 50%">
        <ul>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Product</a>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
```